# Render template to variable in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to render template to a variable instead to output?

```
res.render('list.ejs', {
    posts: posts
});
```

something like this

```
var list = render('list.ejs', {
    posts: posts
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to pass a callback to `res.render`, in your example:

```
res.render('list.ejs', {posts: posts}, function(err, list){
  // 
});
```

But if you want to render partial templates in order to include them in another template you definitely should have a look at [view partials](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-partials).

Comment: i need to load partial by ajax in json response

Comment: so does this work? I don't want to actually render a page back to the user, I want to include the rendered string in a res.json() response.

Comment: Yes, this works. The default callback, which is what would have rendered the page back to the user, is not called when you pass in your own.

Comment: This is ok, but its kind of a pain that there isn't a simpler synchronous solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am quite a newbie on express.js, anyway I am not sure you can access the rendered string that way, although if you look at express' "view.js" source on github ([here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/view.js#L308)) you see that it's accepting a callback as second argument, if that may help: you may access the rendered string there.

Otherwise, I think it's quite easy to patch the code to add a method returning the rendered string without sending it: [on line #399](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/view.js#L399) you have the very call that gives the string you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't the question originally asked, but based on comments from the OP and others, it seems like the goal is to render a partial via json (jsonp), which is something I just had to do.

It's pretty easy:

```
app.get('/header', function (req, res)
{
    res.render('partials/header', { session: req.session, layout: null }, function (err, output)
    {
        res.jsonp({ html: output });
    });    
});
```

Note: In my case, the header partial required the session, and my template library (express-hbs) needed `layout: null` to render the partial without using the default layout.

You can then call this from Javascript code in the client like any other JSONP endpoint.