# Is there a way to render a NodeJs Express view to a variable?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to render an express view to a variable as opposed to the response stream?

```
 var view = path.join( __dirname, '/../customer-product/views/copysheet.html');
res.render( view, {
  data: product
})
```

I need the html on the server side so that I can be passed to PhantomJs for PDF generation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625410/render-template-to-variable-in-expressjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625410/render-template-to-variable-in-expressjs)

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good [article on it at Strongloop](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/bypassing-express-view-rendering-for-speed-and-modularity/).  The upshot is that you would interact directly with the view engine like so:

```
var templatePath = require.resolve('./copysheet.html');
var templateFn = require('jade').compileFile(templatePath); // or whatever view engine you're usingg
var output = templateFn({data:product});
```