# How do we get the html string of an ejs page and store its value in a string in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want the following controller to return an html string as it's response. Currently am hard coding the string in the controller which I feel is not the correct way to do it.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var employeeDetails; // JSON File Containing Details 
    // I need ejs to build the page using employeeDetails and store that as a 
    // string and return this string as the response    
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render template to variable in expressjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625410/render-template-to-variable-in-expressjs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the template as a string, you can call `ejs.render(template)`.

You would have to read your template file as a string first, so you´d end up doing something like this:

```
import * as ejs from 'ejs';
import { readFile as _readFile } from 'fs';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const readFile = promisify(_readFile);

router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    const template = await readFile(/* your template */, 'utf-8');
    const employeeDetails = await readFile(/* your json file */, 'utf-8');
    const html = ejs.render(template, { /* your data */ });

    // now you have your rendered html as a string
    // and can e.g.:

    res.send(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand your question, following maybe a solution.
you can render the page and send the json as an object and in the front end render them using ejs...

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var employeeDetails; // JSON File Containing Details
    employeeDetails=employeeDetails.parse;
    res.render('your site',{data:employeeDetails});
});
```

try this?

Comment: no, i want to send the html string as the response. Don't want to display the page with the data.

Comment: if you say what you intend to do with this html string, I may be able to help