# Create HTML dynamically depending of Node variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Node.js with Express as a server. The user can upload a .CSV file with data. I'm parsing these data and store this in a main array composed of arrays (each line = one array). For now, I'm rendering a page (made with Pug) with this variable.

```
res.render('index', { rows });
```

The page is rendering as I would like to the user. However, I'd like to save the rendered "index" in a HTML file. The goal is to convert the HTML file into a PDF (which already works as a result of previous tests with static HTML).

Is it possible to save the rendered page as a HTML file? I'd like to take advantage of the feature of passing variable through the render function.

Another solution would be to generate by myself the HTML file, and do my own logic inside the Node.js route. That seems a long and useless solution since the render function do it well. I just need to save it instead of rendering it.

Comment: googeled "express render to variable" looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625410/render-template-to-variable-in-expressjs

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. That's perfect. Didn't find that when looking for it. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

You could call PUG directly to trigger a render and then save the produced file (https://pugjs.org/)